youtube caption download using youtube v3 api
I used GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions api to get the captions list which returns like this
{
  "kind": "youtube#captionListResponse",
  "etag": "V4ixyY6VwcMboAfZRMkg5UA4trM",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#caption",
      "etag": "4Uk_V50p_bLjKsPKh9KN2SNnSS8",
      "id": "AUieDaaDF0pplLiwXqJ0-intXtS-3LwTRsMjwu7HFSrs02wNGjM"
    }
  ]
}

then I want to download the captions using the GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/AUieDaaDF0pplLiwXqJ0-intXtS-3LwTRsMjwu7HFSrs02wNGjM
but i get 404 not found.. how to download the caption for any youtube video.. is the above process is incorrect? the video is not owned by me .. does the owner has to give permission to download transcript
?

See the Stack Overflow comment 49414961.

Your request was blocked because the request is being made via a URL w/o an API Key, which is key. ;) See documentation for step-by-step easy-to-follow tutorial: API Reference | Calling the API
Further reading:

Open the Credentials page in the API Console.
This API supports two types of credentials. Create whichever
credentials are appropriate for your project:


OAuth 2.0: Whenever your application requests private user data, it must send an OAuth 2.0 token along with the request. Your application first sends a client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications.
API keys: A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token must
send an API key. The key identifies your project and provides API
access, quota, and reports.

The API supports several types of restrictions on API keys. If the API key that you need doesn't already exist, then create an API key in the Console by clicking Create credentials  > API key. You can restrict the key before using it in production by clicking Restrict key and selecting one of the Restrictions.

no i made the call with the token .. looks we can not download the one's we do not own ..refer to comment in the original question above
